# How to install drivers for intel GMA 3600 intergrated graphics system?

Tags: debian, drivers, crunchbang, intel-gma

I am currently using crunchbang 11 32bit, on a laptop with Atom D2500/GMA3600. Does anyone know how to install a more modern driver - rather than the gma500? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to graphics drivers, intel is the most liberal towards contributing code to the linux kernel. So I think you wont find any references online on how to install a specific kernel driver for intel hardware - its because the kernel will always contain the required drivers. You just need to install a latest linux distribution containing a recent kernel.

Comment: Ive tried wheezy and ubuntu 14.04. I dont seem to be getting any 3d acceleration

Comment: I actually thought that `GMA3600` is a pure intel hardware, but its not. There is some useful info on arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_GMA3600
Try enabling modesetting as mentioned in there

Comment: I went ahead and installed `xserver-xorg-video-modesetting` but when I modified the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-gpudriver.conf` as they suggested it caused a fatal error when xserver tried to start

Comment: I suggest you ask in the appropriate distro's mailing list with the error log you encounter. There would more experienced people who can answer, which might even include people who package that driver itself. This is a bit generic place.

Comment: Bad news for you https://gist.github.com/Aissen/2925633
Thats just 5 months ago. I dont know whats the latest situation.

Comment: Wait and hope I guess, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Maybe the comments made to me would help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265701/intel-gma-3600-linux-support/265712?noredirect=1#comment461888_265712