# Intel GMA 3600 Linux support

Tags: gpu, intel-gma, atom

I am working with an embedded board which includes an **Intel Atom N2600** processor and a GPU **GMA 3600** series based on the PowerVR SGX 545 graphics core (developed by Imagination) [[Link1]](http://www.muylinux.com/2012/06/14/cuidado-con-los-intel-atom-cerdaview-cedar-trail-soporte-complejo-en-linux).

As far as I know, Intel just offers Windows 7 support for its GPU through a driver in [Link2](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/23473). In my case, I am working under **Linux**, so I need to know if there exists any possibility of enabling the GPU capabilities using any compatible driver loaded when X server is started.

Is this impossible? Does the driver just go with a 3.2 Linux kernel, such as in this answer [Link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290515/how-to-install-intel-cedarview-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-10-or-higher)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Videocards of this series [always have troubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#PowerVR_based_chips_on_Linux) with Linux support.

I know that

- **Fedora 17** supports CedarView chipset (with `gma500` driver).
- **Ubuntu 13.04** with community driver supports too. Or **Ubuntu 12.04.1** with proprietary driver.
- I found some [useful information](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_GMA3600) about **Arch** support.

But if you want 3D-video decoding support, you can get into trouble.

P.S.: some years ago I had a netbook with this chipset. So I sold it. :)

Comment: I have seen this video, where using a propietary driver and a Fedora-based Linux an Intel Atom N2600 runs FULL HD https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpQwcOaI8J8. Would it just work under Fedora 17 or maybe using a newer one would also work?

Comment: @aloplop85 current (and the final) driver version 1.0.3 require **Kernel: 3.1.0, Mesa GL: 7.11, Xorg: 1.11**, so I have some doubts about a newer OS...

Comment: In newer Linux kernels, such as 3.12.20, it appears this option CONFIG_DRM_GMA3600. Would it be useful to enable it or do I need also newer Mesa GL and Xorg versions?

Comment: @aloplop85 Proprietary driver require versions of **Mesa** and **Xorg**. Built-in driver doesnt require it. You can try, but there will be problems with 3d acceleration, high resolution... Maybe.

Comment: Once rebuilt the kernel with the option...how should I enable the built-in driver? What driver is it supposed to be included in the xorg.conf file?

Comment: @aloplop85 Did you install `xserver-xorg-video-modesetting`? In `xorg.conf` you can try options from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_GMA3600) ("Xorg driver" section)

Comment: Aha! In the Linux version I am using (Slack 13.1) I don't have such driver... and it may be impossible to build it for a 1.7.7 Xorg server

Comment: @aloplop85 Unfortunately, this driver possibly cannot work with modern configuration of environment. But you can use GPU capabilities using old Linux dist.

Comment: Slack 13.1 is quite an old one...however I cannot build xf86-video-modesetting-0.1.0 driver. It seems to be a problem with Xorg (1.7.7), so I'm afraid I should move to another 'newer' such as the ones in Arch-Linux page. E.g.: Bundle Bee Xorg 1.11 or Ant with Xorg 1.9

Comment: xf86-video-modesetting-0.1.0 driver has dependencies with xorg-macros 1.8 so...1.7.7 is not valid.

Comment: I have tried with Ubuntu 14.04 on that CPU. During startup, gma500 driver is loaded. Moreover, I start X with modesetting driver (in xorg.conf) but I'm afraid it is not working...

Comment: @aloplop85 try to play with `gma500` in xorg.conf. Or maybe VESA will work.

Comment: vesa and Gstreamer-1.0 seems to work ok. Also fbdev, http://askubuntu.com/questions/158721/which-xorg-driver-not-kernel-driver-to-use-with-gma500-poulsbo-video-hardware  :)

Comment: Maybe the problem is that GStreamer works in a different way with this kind of GPU...do you know any example?

Comment: @aloplop85 I did not experiment with GStreamer when I had this chipset, so I do not know...

Comment: With Fedora 16 and Intel documentation four XV channels are loaded (not easy, though...). Ubuntu 12.04.1 has also the pvr_drv driver for Xorg, which requires exactly Xorg 1.11: PVR was compiled for 1.11.3 module. Not easy to enable GPU capabilities for this chip...

Comment: Solutions: Fedora 16 with Intel guide to compile de xorg driver & Ubuntu 12.04.1, where pvr_dvr can be download from repositories. Note the '.1' is not the LTS version.